# puppet: `puppet resource <defined_type>` does not show defined type

Tags: puppet

I created a test.pp file and put in it a defined type that basically creates a file at /tmp/asdf. I ran `puppet apply test.pp` and verified that the file got created. However, when I go to `puppet resource -t`, I don't see that type listed, and I also don't see it when I try:

```
puppet resource hello_define
Error: Could not run: Could not find type hello_define
```

I loosely followed this guide:

https://soivi.net/2013/define-types-example-in-puppet/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The puppet resource tool doesn't work with defined types, but only built-in types and custom (Ruby) types that have a properly implemented `self.instances` method.  Have a look at this thread for instance: [ref](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/puppet-dev/l19aUi6Pvok).  HTH.

Comment: This follows from the fact that defined types are known to Puppet only as a result of evaluating manifests, which `puppet resource` does not do, and does not have sufficient information to do properly even if it wanted to.